# Eliminar divs en responsive

Tags: responsive, div, eliminar

`Buenas!!soy nuevita acá y ya se darán cuenta, estoy practicando responsive y no logro entender(debe sr una pavada), busqué en otros lados pero no logro respuesta,paso de un @media de 900px,luego 650px y el último 300px, los dos primeros fueron creados con 4 divs, de los cuales uno tiene 2 elementos, quiero q el último media sólo tenga 3 divs, como hago para indicar q uno sea eliminado? repito q soy nuevisima.gracias!!!
pd  no subo el código porq me salta error,,me advierte q hy demasiado código

Answer (score 0):

Una pena que te hayan votado negativo.

Prueba aplicándole a tu div el atributo `display:none` de esta forma:

```
<!--Tus estilos -->
<style>
@Tu mediaQuery 300px{
#div1{ display: none !important;
}
</style>

<div id="Div1">Hola</div>
```

Con ese ejemplo, estarias ocultando al Div1 definitivamente, o bien, puedes ocupar `visibility: hidden` la diferencia es que con visibility el elemento está ahí, ocupa espacio pero no se muestra.

Comment: excelente muchisimas graciasss, tengo otra consulta ayyy

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió. si crees que eso resolvió tu pregunta, no olvides marcarla como correcta. También aquí en los comentarios puedes poner tu otra consulta o abrir otra pregunta. Saludos!